# Puting an object into providers in @NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, sentry

I am trying to set up sentry on an angular 5 project. The instructs show an object being placed in the providers as seen below:

```
import * as Raven from 'raven-js';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

Raven
.config('https://KEY')
.install();

export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
handleError(err:any) : void {
Raven.captureException(err.originalError);
}
}

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
providers: [ { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RavenErrorHandler } ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My project has a few more things in the providers array, and looks like this:

```
  providers: [
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RavenErrorHandler }, //sentry
MapDataService,
GraphService
]
```

Is this allowed in angular? I'm asking because I am very new to this and I cant get sentry to work and I am just feeling uneasy about this part and before I start looking in to other places I wanted to see if this is OK.

Comment: what is the `RavenErrorHandler` for?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but its in the instructions, the full version is as flows:

Comment: in what instructions? can you please clarify

Comment: Just put full instruction in post above, what I am trying to figure out is if its ok to put an object in the providers array and flow it with other providers as i did.

Comment: but where did you get told to do this? was it a tutorial online? the official docs?

Comment: It was the official docs

Comment: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/integrations/angular/

Comment: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/integrations/angular/

Comment: i would personally create a separate injectable class and manually pass the errors to it and then call the raven capture method

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is completely ok. You are registering three providers in your AppModule - `ErrorHandler`, `MapDataService` and `GraphService`.

And also saying that each time application requires ErrorHandler it should use your own `RavenErrorHandler` instead.